# If Then Select From List

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript, is there a way to select if then from a list. I remember doing it in Visual Basic.

So instead of

```
if (id == "category1") {i = 1};
if (id == "category2") {i = 2};
if (id == "category3") {i = 3};
```

Is there something like

```
if.select (

  category1 = 1
  category2 = 2
  category3 = 3
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe switch is what immediately jumped out to me as well

Comment: switch is close enough to what you are after...

Comment: `i = +(id.replace(/[a-zA-z]/g,""))` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary (works similarly to enum):

```
var dictionary = {"category1": 1, "category2": 2, "category3": 3}; 
i = dictionary[id]
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwxc478z/1/)

Here is a switch case example:

```
switch(id){
  case 'category1':
    i = 1;
    break;
  case 'category2':
    i = 2;
    break;
  case 'category3':
    i = 3;
    break;
}
```

I prefer the dictionary approach over the switch-case approach because it's a bit less code to write every time you add a new category.

Comment: Because it's a terrible answer - what happens if you have 50 categories? How is this better than what OP already has?

Comment: @Shomz And what if the categories are "examples":1, "use cases":2, "etc":3 ? Your answer parses assuming the category starts with the string "category".

Comment: My answers also suggests using `switch`, but we're talking about your answer here. (of course, feel free to comment on mine below, but let's stay on the topic here)

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc The dictionary variable is what seems to be an easy answer to this question. In this case, the number is always proceeded by category, but why would that matter. It seems like this would work for any entries in the dictionary. If switch is a better solution, I would sure like to know how to use it. I looked it up and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @Matt, if that's how you build your IDs, then I'd always pick using one line instead of all the manual work (both with this and the switch solutions).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Using the "dictionary" worked well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can think outside the box:

```
var i = id.split('category')[1];
```

You can make it a function:

```
function getCategoryId(id){
    return id.split('category')[1];
}
```

And then just call it like:

```
var i = getCategoryId('category1');
```

You can also use `substr`, it will perform the best (talking about nanoseconds, though).

---

See it live here:

```js
var id = 'category2';
function getCategoryId(id){
    return id.split('category')[1];
}
alert(getCategoryId(id));
```

---

Or just use `switch`:

```
switch(id){
  case 'category1':
    i = 1;
    break;
  case 'category2':
    i = 2;
    break;
  case 'category3':
    i = 3;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out the switch function. I was confused by the code I looked at on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. Your example is very clear. Now that I see it, "Case" was the syntax used in Visual Basic.

Comment: Yeah, `console.log` is probably the quickest/easiest way to debug things in JS. However, I strongly suggest you use one of the approaches from my first paragraph since you won't have to do any manual work when adding/removing categories as long as their format is `"categoryXX"`.

Comment: I ended up using the "dictionary", but switch is also a very good option. It is what I was think of when I asked this question and good to know for future projects. Ah! . . . console.log . . . I get it now. I have learned a lot about JavaScript in two days. Thanks for your help.